# Expectation of truncated normal X conditional on truncated normal Y

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am trying to derive:

$E(X|a \leq Y \leq b)$

where $c \leq X \leq d $, $X$ and $Y$ are (doubly truncated) Gaussians with the same mean and different variance, and $a < c < d < b$ are the truncation points.

To start off, I wrote:

$E(X|a \leq Y \leq b) = \int_c^d x f_{X|c \leq Y \leq d}(x)dx $

where

$f_{X|c \leq Y \leq d}(x) = \frac{f_{X}(x)}{Pr(c \leq Y \leq d)} =
\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_x}\phi (\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})}{\Phi(\frac{d-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}) - \Phi(\frac{c-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})}}{\Phi(\frac{d-\mu_y}{\sigma_y}) - \Phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}, \forall c \leq Y \leq d
$

At this point I'm absolutely stuck. Is what I wrote correct? Is there any other way to derive the result more directly?